# How can i convert a float number to a string?

Tags: c#

How can i convert  a float number to a string?

```
for (float i = 1000000000; i < 10000000000; i++)
{
     //temp never change and it's value is 1000000000
     string temp = Convert.ToInt64(i).ToString();

}
```

this number is big and i want to save i as string on a file like

```
1000000001
1000000002
1000000003
```

Comment: Just change your `i` as `long`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i convert a float number to a string?

Obviously: `i.ToString()`. See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn how to apply formatting in order to achieve the desired output.

However, a couple notes:

- A variable named `i` commonly indicates `int` and not `float`.
- Iterating with a `for` and a variable of type `float` is obscure.
- Are you sure your want a to use a floating-point data type, when actually you treat it as an integer? Consider using a `long` or a `decimal`.

> temp never change and it's value is 1000000000

`float`'s precision is *not enough* to store a number as big as even `1000000000` and just discards the least significant places. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format): “All integers with six or less significant decimal digits can be converted to an IEEE 754 floating point value.” That's why the result seems the same. As a side effect, your `for` cycle will never end.

Hence, first of all, ask yourself why have you declared the variable being of type `float` *at the very first place*? Especially because of the conversion to `long` in your code, anyway. Consider using `long` or maybe `decimal`. Then your code will work.